# Vitepress prepends previous route segment to next route

Tags: vue.js, vuepress, vitepress

I have a Vitepress 1.0.0-alpha.40 project with the following configuration

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitepress'

export default defineConfig({
    base: './',
    outDir: '../dist',
    themeConfig: {
        sidebar: [
            {
                text: 'Configuration',
                collapsible: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Foo',
                        link: '/configuration/foo'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: 'Deployment',
                collapsible: true,
                items: [
                    {
                        text: 'Bar',
                        link: '/deployment/bar'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

and the following folder structure

```
.
└── docs
    ├── .vitepress
    │   └── config.ts
    ├── configuration
    │   └── foo.md
    ├── deployment
    │    └── bar.md
    └── index.md
```

When running the application on http://localhost:5173/ I see the following

[image]

When clicking on the sidebar link **Foo** it works fine, the router navigates to

> http://localhost:5173/configuration/foo.html

But when I now click **Bar** the router navigates to

> http://localhost:5173/configuration/deployment/bar.html

which is wrong. The expected url would be

> http://localhost:5173/deployment/bar.html

It seems it always adds the previous segment e.g. "/configuration".

Does someone know how to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This happened because you put `./` in the `base` configuration.

Either put something other like `/` (default) or `/base/`.

Or remove the config altogether.

Comment: I need to use a relative path ( https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base ) because the Apache deployment server is not able to deal with an absolute path

Comment: At which level is it not able to handle an aboslute path ?

Comment: Also do you need to need a complex server with apache for this site. As this can be easily deployed with any static site provider as netlify, render.com, cloudflare or vercel

Comment: When building a Vue app without a relative path the .html file has `<script type="module" src="/src/main.ts"></script>` but the Apache server needs `<script type="module" src="./src/main.ts"></script>` . I do not own the deployment infrastructure